# Какая разница при объявлении функции в reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Объясните есть ли какая разница при объявление функций, и влияет ли это как-то на скорость работы компонентов?

```
class Content extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.consoleLog = () => { 
      //Первый вариант объявления
      console.log('Первый вариант');
    }
  }

    consoleLog = () => { 
    //Второй вариант объявления
    console.log('Второй вариант');
  }

  consoleLog() { 
    //Третий вариант объявления
    console.log('Третий вариант');
  }
}
```

Comment: React.js тут не причем. Вопрос исключительно по ES2015

Comment: Просто читал где-то что это может влиять на скорость работы компонента в react.js

Comment: Первый и второй вариант идентичны, третий вариант кроме очевидного устанавливает дескрипторы (конкретно здесь `consoleLog` не будет `enumerable`). Если что-то и влияет на скорость работы компонентов, то это определенно не способ объявления функции.